# Error in my Vim mapping

Tags: vim

I would like to map `Control` + `F3` with `map <c-f3> :w <CR> :make <CR><CR><CR>`. When I leave out the `Control` this works fine. With `control` from normal command mode insert mode is entered and `1;5R` is inserted into the buffer.

When I use a simpler command e.g. `map <c-f3> dd` this works as expected.

With `Shift` instead of `control` I get a similar behavior (`1;2R` inserted into buffer). What can I do get my mapping right?

Edit: I want the command to be executed from normal command mode. However, vim enters insert mode, which is not desired.

Comment: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of function keys and modifiers is problematic in terminal Vim; whether this works depends on the terminal.

- Check your `$TERM` value; a wrong one can cause these problems. Also, your *termcap database* must be correct and complete.
- Try out another terminal (`gnome-terminal` vs. `konsole` vs. `xterm`); it may work there.
- Alternatively, use GVIM; it doesn't have these problems (but still can't map some other combinations).

If you use varying terminals, it's best to avoid these key combinations, and just use plain `<F1..12>`, and `<Leader>...` for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

`map` defines keystrokes for normal, visual and operation modes. For insert mode you should use `imap`.
Something like this I believe: `imap <c-f3> <esc>:w :make <cr><cr><cr>`. `<ESC>` puts the Vim to normal mode.

`:he :key-mapping` for explaining.

Comment: I do not want to execute the command from insert mode. The problem is that vim enters insert mode when the keys are pressed, instead of executing the desired command sequence.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. What's OS and (g)vim, terminal emulator? Behaviors for shortcuts with Function especially with modifications key not only vim related. I think.